# When I install fusion builder it says on home page "avada Fusion_Dynamic_CSS_Helpers::get_dynamic_css_id()"

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

This is the full error message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Fusion_Dynamic_CSS_Helpers::get_dynamic_css_id() in C:\wamp\www\softtech\wp-content\plugins\fusion-builder\inc\lib\inc\class-fusion-dynamic-css-file.php on line 112

And this is the file code of the line of 112. How to solve this. I tried removing all the code from the file but it's making more error.

```
    public function file( $target = 'path' ) {

    // Get the blog ID.
    $blog_id = '';
    // If this is a multisite installation, append the blogid to the filename.
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        $current_site = get_blog_details();
        if ( $current_site->blog_id > 1 ) {
            $blog_id = "_blog-{$current_site->blog_id}";
        }
    }

    $fusion_library = Fusion::get_instance();
    $id             = $this->dynamic_css->get_helpers()->get_dynamic_css_id();
    $file_name      = "{$id}.min.css";
    if ( $blog_id ) {
        $file_name = "{$blog_id}-{$id}.min.css";
    }

    if ( 'filename' === $target ) {
        return $file_name;
    }

    $file = new Fusion_Filesystem( $file_name, 'fusion-styles' );

    // Return the path or the URL
    // depending on the $target we have defined when calling this method.
    if ( 'path' === $target ) {
        return $file->get_path();
    }
    return $file->get_url();

}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

On line 112: `$this->dynamic_css->get_helpers()->get_dynamic_css_id()` the `get_helpers()` come from the `wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-dynamic-css.php`, this file has the method

`public function get_helpers() {
    // Instantiate the Fusion_Dynamic_CSS_Helpers object.
    if ( null === $this->helpers ) {
        $this->helpers = new Fusion_Dynamic_CSS_Helpers();
    }
    error_log(print_r(get_class_methods($this->helpers), true));
    return $this->helpers;
}`

The problem is that `Fusion_Dynamic_CSS_Helpers` conflicts with the plugin `fusion-builder`. So, I solved this by importing 
`require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/fusion-builder/inc/lib/inc/class-fusion-dynamic-css-helpers.php';` that contain the method `get_dynamic_css()`

**Quick answer**

Insert `require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/fusion-builder/inc/lib/inc/class-fusion-dynamic-css-helpers.php';` in the begin of `wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/class-fusion-dynamic-css.php`